# Count of pages scrolled in the past few sec

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

In my `Activity`, I want to know count of pages scrolled(in my `ViewPager`) in the past few sec

I have implemented `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` using which I can get the current page by overriding `onPageSelected`.

I am wondering is there a way to count the number of pages swiped or scrolled in the past few sec.(i.e., in the past 10 sec).

I thought of using `Handler` and `SharedPreferences`(using to can save selected page number), but I think this is not an optimistic way. Can any one suggest me how to implement this.

Comment: Hi Please provide more context to your question and more details of the things you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a count variable,

increment it in your `pageChangeListener`, and reset it when the time is out.

UPDATE:
in your pageChangeListener:

```
count ++;
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       count = 0;                       
    }
}, 10000);
```

Comment: but, that is going to create multiple `Handler`'s, is there anyway we can do it in a single handler?? And I wont have individual `count` variable instance for each `Handler`

Comment: maybe you can try to create a single handler and put a pageChangeListenr inside it with a same logic